# ExtJs 4.2 compiling theme using compass

Tags: extjs, themes, extjs4.2

According to Sencha's documentation creating and compiling new themes should be done using Sencha CMD.

I'd like to create a new theme (which will inherit from an existing one) and to be able to compile it using Compass **without** Sencha CMD.

Any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new theme from scratch, that would be a bit overwhelming probably and I'd recommend trying to extend an existing theme first. Basically, a theme consists of two large parts: CSS templates and JavaScript overrides; CSS in turn is split between SASS code, mixins and variables.

There's the [Theming guide](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/guide/theming) that discuss theme building for 4.2; for inheritance examples you can take a look at existing themes: e.g., gray theme which extends classic theme, which in turn inherits from neutral theme, which has base theme as a parent. Neptune can give you lots of JavaScript override examples, too.

Comment: Thank for the detailed response, but this doesn't really answer my question in any way.

Comment: Sorry, I have missed "without Sencha Cmd" part. Is there any particular reason to avoid Cmd?

Comment: 1. no way I install it on the build machine. 2. it's slow. 3. `compass watch`.

Comment: What's the difficulty with installing it? Maybe we can fix the problem.

Comment: @AlexTokarev is there a way to build sencha theme without SenchaCmd? Something like lightweight and _quick_ SASS builder based on grunt/gulp - to have the SASS rebuild on watcher and spend 1-5 seconds for the rebuild instead of 20-40 seconds like we have with SenchaCmd.

Comment: @webdevbyjoss Check out Sencha Cmd 6.0 with new SASS compiler named Fashion - it's JavaScript based and very fast.

Comment: thanks @AlexTokarev. Other option may be to use the bundled version of compass directly.

For ex. we use ExtJS 4.2.x and old Sencha Cmd 4.0.4.x - so in order to build the CSS you could just call: 

$ GEM_HOME=$SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0/extensions/sencha-compass/gems GEM_PATH=$SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0/extensions/sencha-compass/gems ruby $SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0/extensions/sencha-compass/gems/bin/compass compile . --config ./config.rb --css-dir ./resources --sass-dir . --force --trace 

It builds the theme in ~2-3 seconds which is quite fast and enough for any custom grunt/gulp based watcher.

Answer (score 0):

We have had theming in our application for last Ext 4 was released without the sencha command tool.  Keep in mind this is 4.1 code and it may have have changed since 4.2.  You need to have ruby/compass installed and create a config file for compass that will tell it to load ext specific variables and you can set compass configuration variables.  http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/

Here is a sample config file named config.rb (I think it needs to be named config.rb but don't quote me.)  This is taken from extDir/resources/sass

```
# $ext_path: This should be the path of where the ExtJS SDK is installed
# Generally this will be in a lib/extjs folder in your applications root
# <root>/lib/extjs
$ext_path = "../extjs/4.1"

# sass_path: the directory your Sass files are in. THIS file should also be in the Sass folder
sass_path = File.dirname(__FILE__)

# css_path: the directory you want your CSS files to be.
# Generally this is a folder in the parent directory of your Sass files
css_path = File.join(sass_path, "css")

# We need to load in the Ext4 themes folder, which includes all it's default styling, images, variables and mixins
load File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), $ext_path, 'resources', 'themes')

#Compass config variable
relative_assets = true
```

Here is the dir structure

- sass/config.rb
- sass/redTheme.sass
- sass/css

The redTheme.sass might look something like:

```
$base-color: red;

@import 'compass';
@import 'ext4/default/all';
```

After a compass compile in the sass directory it will create redTheme.css

- sass/css/redTheme.css

Comment: @CD.. were you ever able to find an answer to your question? I am just now looking for a solution that allows me to use compass watch for developing Sencha 4.2 themes.  Running Sencha Cmd just seems really heavy and slow.

Comment: @David: Unfortunately, I have not found a solution.

Comment: What a shame. No wonder all the themes you can download suck so bad.  Theming is frustrating at best.